# Sconfig not found - Server Core 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to run sconfig, but I get the error:

> CScript Error: Execution of the Windows Script Host failed. (The system cannot find the file specified.)
>
> ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

Running Server Core 2012 R2 on a Dell pc

Comment: Were you on the system drive when you ran it?

Comment: Yes, I was on the system drive.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same. Did you by chance install in a different language than en-US?

I have to open it from `c:\windows\system32\de-DE\`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a recurrent problem with other languages installs. E.g. I have the spanish version, same error cannot find sconfig.vbs but it searches in this path: \windows\system32\en-US\

Trick:
Go to your language path, e.g. \windows\system32\es-ES\ and copy the sconfig.vbs to the \en-US\

sconfig should run now from powershell

Comment:
This is why I hate installing in other languages, and I can't believe MS is so lazy. An older problem was trying to copy AD from Windows Server 2003 English to another 2003 but Spanish -> it never worked. But from Eng to Eng it was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding the WMI Repository

For Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2008 R2, you can run

winmgmt /verifyrepository 
from a command prompt.

For Older OS like Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 run: WmiDiag tool with the checkconsistency option. For example: WmiDiag checkconsistency

If repository is found to be inconsistent:

```
a. For Vista and newer, run from elevated command prompt:
```

Winmgmt /salvagerepository

Note this command will take the content of the inconsistent repository and merge it into the rebuilt repository if it is readable

If the above doesn’t work, then run:

Winmgmt /resetrepository

Note this will reset repository to the initial state when the OS was first installed